# Match Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript to validate my form fields, and the below regular expression is not working. Am I using the wrong method to match?

```
var name=document.getElementById('first_name').value;

if (!name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*$/))
{
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please match the regxp";
    document.getElementById('first_name').focus();
    return false;
}
```

i am executing the above code on form submit.

Comment: The regex seems to work just fine, of course depending on what you're expecting -> **http://jsfiddle.net/q4da7/**

Comment: Where does this code run? (It should run in a form-submit event or something like that)

Comment: try after removing return false; from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it...

To match a regular expression, I used the below method...

```
var pattern=/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
if (!pattern.test(document.getElementById('first_name').value))
{
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "only the characters and 0-9 are allowed";
    document.getElementById('first_name').focus();
    return false;
}
```

By the way, thanks for all your reply

Answer (score 0):

The `*` repetition operator matches *zero* or more occurrences, so the regular expression `^[A-Za-z]*$` will match zero or more occurrences of a letter, i.e. it will match the empty string as well as a string containing only letters.

You probably meant to use the `+` repetition operator to match 1 or more like `^[A-Za-z]+$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Using Regex would do that.

```
function validateName(x){
    var name=document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    var pattern = new RegExp('/^\w+$/');
    if(!pattern.test(name)){
       alert("Use only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or _ in names.");
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use RegExp, he was already using a regex expression with /^[A-Za-z]*$/

Comment: one way to do that. Cool anyways

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your problem is in the code you posted, is that bound properly to an event handler?

It works fine in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dD6y3/

Just added on blur binding, maybe it's what you are missing? or what is wrong? Hard to say without seeing more code.

```
$('#first_name').on("blur", function() {

  var name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;

    if (!name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*$/)) {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Please match the regxp";
        document.getElementById('first_name').focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression seems to be ok, have you attached the event to the input?
You should add the event so as to check whether it's correct or not: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

Here's my solution, it checks the error when you deselect the input, when you change to another input:

**HTML**

```
<div id='error'></div>
<input id='first_name' onchange="checkChanges()"/>
```

Although this will work, you should use Event Handlers or a framerowk such as jQuery so as to guarantee it'll work on all possible browsers

**JS**

```
function checkChanges() {
var name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;

if (!name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*$/))
{
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Please match the regxp";
    document.getElementById('first_name').focus();
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="OK";
}
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LMY6t/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your name to begin with a letter, and you're not using jQuery...

```
var errors = document.getElementById('error');
var firstName = document.getElementById('first_name');

function validate(element) {
  var name = element.value;
  if (name.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) {
      return true;
  }
  errors.innerHTML = "Name must begin with a letter";
  element.focus();
  return false;
}

validate(firstName);  // needs moving to a submit event handler or similar
```